# Como consultar datos repetidos MYSQL y mostrarlos en un JTable en netbeans

Tags: java, mysql

Buen Día, Como podría llenar un JTable con los datos repetidos una tabla en MYSQL, Les dejo unas fotos para que me entiendan mejor.

[image: Estos son los registros que tengo]

La imagen anterior muestra los datos que tengo en mi tabla de "Productos_vendidos"

[image: Consulta]

En la imagen anterior, tengo la consulta que me muestra los datos repetidos y la cantidad de veces que se repitieron, ahora mi pregunta es: El resultado de esa consulta que se muestra en una tabla de 3 campos ("Codigo_Producto, Nombre_Producto, Num_repetidos"), como hago para mostrarla en un JTable de netbeans
[image: JTable Java]

La anterior es mi Jframe que contiene el JTable y los botones de consultar, y limpiar la tabla, si me pueden explicar como tendría que hacerlo con detalles se los agradecería, o decirme/mostrarme algún ejemplo del cual pueda guiarme. Muchas gracias por el tiempo. Buen Día!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante complejo de explicar en un post. Te dejo un vídeo para que veas lo que tienes que hacer.

En resumidas cuentas, tu tendrías que ir directamente al punto 3, dado que es cuando añade la librería de conexión entre Java y el motor de MySQL. Una vez configurada la cadena de conexión, creas una clase para conectar con la BBDD, hacer la consulta cuando tocas el botón, etc.

Vídeo: [Vídeo conexión NetBeans y MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zec_bS9Bb40)